# ASP.NET Core custom claims are lost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When a user logs in, I want to assign add claims to the cookie. Initially, this works perfectly, but after a little while those claims are lost. There have been similar questions on the topic, but none of those seem to work anymore on ASP.NET Core 6.x.

The `Startup` class:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppDbContext>()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyAppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicatonUserStore>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddTransient<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, MyAppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

services
.AddAuthentication("MyApp")
.AddCookie(options =>
{
  options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
  options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
  options.SlidingExpiration = true;
  options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
});
```

The `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` class:

```cs
public class MyAppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
  protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
  {
    ClaimsIdentity identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
    identity.AddClaims(user.GetAdditionalClaims());
    return identity;
  }
 }
```

In the `AccountController`, I simply call `await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(viewModel.UserName, viewModel.Password, true, false);`  to sign in the user.

Suggestions in other articles claim that the problem could be solved by using another cookie in the `AddAuthentication()` call to prevent the cookie from being refreshed (and the custom claims to be cleared). This doesn't seem to make any difference as the claims are always lost.

Any idea how this should be implemented in ASP.NET Core 6?

Comment: According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side, I found after add the claims, the claims will add to the cookie's `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application`.  I couldn't understand what you mean these claims are lost. Since this part is added into the cookie, if the cookie is not expired, it will not miss.

Comment: It's basically the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426024/additional-claims-missing-in-asp-net-core-identity-after-30-minutes, but then for the latest version of ASP.NET Core. After a while, the claims I added through the IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory implementation are no longer available in the cookie. So ASP.NET Core is definitely doing something like refreshing the cookie. That's what MS themselves say too: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10328#issuecomment-493451017.

Comment: Have you tried to use [claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Of course, but sadly not an option. I need access to the user retrieved from ASP.NET Core Identity to add claims. IClaimsTransformation doesn't provide that capability afaik.

Comment: Check out this answer for .NET 6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76790172/8644294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the culprit myself. It turns out that it *did* have something to do with the cookie refresh process.

My `ApplicationUser` class has a navigation property, which contains all the information that my custom claims transformation class uses to fill up the claims. So all is good there.

Except that I didn't override the `UserStore`'s
`Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))` method, which is invoked when the cookie is refreshed. By default, Identity won't load this navigation property, in which case the object is null and the claims will be 'lost' in the process.

So in the end I added an override and added some eager loading, and the problem was resolved.

Comment: can you tell me what did you do? I have the same problem and based on your answer I can't figure out what to do.

Comment: The override of the user store class, the one where you eager load your navigation properties (ie the one you add during startup; .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()), didn't override all methods. So I added an override for FindByIdAsync, added my code to eager load extra properties, and the IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory instance did its job perfectly. Does that make sense?

Comment: An example would have been nice.