# Custom claims lost after sometime in AspNetCore Identity cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I see a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23622047/8644294) that was already asked years ago that explains a problem related to losing custom claims while using AspNet Identity. The solution mentioned there unfortunately doesn't work for me as I'm using AspNet **Core** Identity on a .NET 6 Blazor Server app.

The issue is similar (explained in points below):

1. I add some claims during login (these claims come from some API call and not from Identity db, so I add them during login).
2. I access them from Blazor components just fine.
3. It works fine 30% of the time, but for 70% of the time, the cookie loses custom claims that I added during login and my app runs into issues. I'm not even able to figure out when those claims get lost as that's not happening during `RevalidationInterval` either as I tested it with a TimeSpan of 1 minute and it worked well for at least 5 minutes when I tested it multiple times. Searched up bunch of answers and found no proper answer for AspNet **Core** Identity.

This is how my code looks like:

1. Identity setup in Program.cs

```
    builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        // Set Password options here if you'd like:
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    })
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddUserManager<ADUserManager<IdentityUser>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
```

2. Adding claims during Login in Login.cshtml.cs

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();
    
        try
        {
            var adLoginResult = ADHelper.ADLogin(Input.Username, Input.Password);
            
            // Use adLoginResult data to populate custom claims here
            // Set additional info about the user using empTimeId and other custom claims
            var customClaims = new[]
            {
                new Claim("EmployeeTimeId", adLoginResult.TimeId)
            };
    
            // SignIn the user now
            await _signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, Input.RememberMe, customClaims);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Login Failed. Error: {ex.Message}.");
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

3. Revalidation method in RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider.cs

```
    public class RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<TUser>
        : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider where TUser : class
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
        private readonly IdentityOptions _options;
    
        public RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider(
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
            : base(loggerFactory)
        {
            _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
            _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }
    
        protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); // More frequent for ease of testing
    
        protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
            var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    
            try
            {
                var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
                return await ValidateSecurityTimeStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
            }
            finally
            {
                if(scope is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
                {
                    await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    scope.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    
        private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityTimeStampAsync(UserManager<TUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
            if(user == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(_options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
                var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
                return principalStamp == userStamp;
            }
        }
    }
```

4. Retrieving auth information

```
    public class UserInfoService
    {
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _dbContextFactory;
    
        public UserInfoService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider, IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextFactory)
        {
            _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
            _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
        }
    
        public async Task<UserInfoFromAuthState?> GetCurrentUserInfoFromAuthStateAsync()
        {
            var userInfo = new UserInfoFromAuthState();
    
            var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            if (authState == null ||
                authState.User == null ||
                authState.User.Identity == null ||
                !authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return null;
            }
    
            userInfo.UserName = authState.User.Identity.Name!;
            
            // This comes out to be null after sometime a user has logged in
            userInfo.EmployeeTimeId = int.TryParse(authState.User.FindFirstValue("EmployeeTimeId", out var timeId) ? timeId : null;
    
            return userInfo;
        }
    }
```

This is where I face problem when I get null on my custom claim: `"EmployeeTimeId"`.

Comment: Have you refered to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72506364/asp-net-core-custom-claims-are-lost)?

Comment: Hi @XinranShen, I had already looked at that link and it was not helpful for my case.

Comment: Actually i have found a lot of question have the same issue, But it seems there are a lot of reasons will cause this.

Comment: @XinranShen Finally figured out this issue, check out the accepted answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally figured this out by asking a question in **aspnetcore** github repo.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49610

Much thanks to @halter73 for his help!

---

Turns out the Principal was being replaced whenever the SecurityStamp was revalidated (which happens every 30 minutes as default interval). So, I fixed this issue by re-adding claims whenever the Principal was being refreshed. I used [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-di-services-to-configure-options) to accomplish this.

### Step 1:

Add a new class under Identity folder called `ConfigureSecurityStampOptions.cs` (or anywhere you'd like):

[image]

### Step 2:

Content of `ConfigureSecurityStampOptions.cs` should be:

```
public class ConfigureSecurityStampOptions : IConfigureOptions<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>
{
    public void Configure(SecurityStampValidatorOptions options)
    {
        options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); // Default interval is 30 minutes

        // When refreshing the principal, ensure custom claims that
        // might have been set with an external identity continue
        // to flow through to this new one.
        options.OnRefreshingPrincipal = refreshingPrincipal =>
        {
            ClaimsIdentity? newIdentity = refreshingPrincipal.NewPrincipal?.Identities.First();
            ClaimsIdentity? currentIdentity = refreshingPrincipal.CurrentPrincipal?.Identities.First();

            if (currentIdentity is not null && newIdentity is not null)
            {
                // Since this is refreshing an existing principal, we want to merge all claims.
                // Only work with claims in current identity that are not already present in the new identity with the same Type and Value.
                var currentClaimsNotInNewIdentity = currentIdentity.Claims.Where(c => !newIdentity.HasClaim(c.Type, c.Value));

                foreach (Claim claim in currentClaimsNotInNewIdentity)
                {
                    newIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    }
}
```

### Step 3:

Register it in `Program.cs`

```
// To ensure custom claims are added to new identity when principal is refreshed.
builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureSecurityStampOptions>();
```

### Full Source Code

https://github.com/akhanalcs/blazor-server-auth/tree/feature/AddClaimsDuringLogin

---

### Bonus

If you're someone who has strict code coverage policy at work and want to unit test this, this is how I've done it. I'm using *xUnit* and *Shouldly* here.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using HMT.Web.Server.Areas.Identity;
using Shouldly;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace HMT.UnitTests.Identity;

public class IdentityTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_Add_CustomClaims_During_Principal_RefreshAsync()
    {
        // Arrange
        var currentIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("Type1", "Value1"), // Claim from Identity Db
            new Claim("Type2", "Value2") // Custom claim
        });

        var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("Type1", "Value1") // Claim from Identity Db
        });

        var options = new SecurityStampValidatorOptions();
        var configureOptions = new ConfigureSecurityStampOptions();

        var refreshingPrincipalCtx = new SecurityStampRefreshingPrincipalContext
        {
            CurrentPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(currentIdentity),
            NewPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity) // To be refreshed principal
        };

        // Act
        configureOptions.Configure(options);

        // Assert
        refreshingPrincipalCtx.NewPrincipal.Claims.Count().ShouldBe(1);

        // Act
        await options.OnRefreshingPrincipal(refreshingPrincipalCtx);

        // Assert
        refreshingPrincipalCtx.NewPrincipal.Claims.Count().ShouldBe(2);
        refreshingPrincipalCtx.NewPrincipal.FindAll(c => c.Type == "Type2" && c.Value == "Value2").Count().ShouldBe(1);
    }
}
```